# how to grab the text of select list option and compare it in an IF statment using jquery

Tags: jquery

i am trying to hide one select list based on another select lists text.
For example if i have a option list

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
<option>select your province</option>
<option>country</option>
</select>
```

And second one is

```
<select id="select2" name="select2">
<option>canada</option>
</select>
```

The scenario i want is that when select your choice option is selected in my #select1 then i want my #select2 list to hide but when i have selected country option in my first list then i want my second list to be visible.
this is the jquery code i have tried but i doesnt seem to be working.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    if($("#select1").text()=="select your province")
    {
        $("#select2").hide();
        }
        else
        {
    $("#select1").change(function(){
        $("#select2").show();

    });
        }
});

</script>
```

Can someone tell me what mistake am i making. I am relatively new to jquery so help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3QnZf/)

JS

```
$('#region').change(function(){
  var selectedregion = $('#region').val();
  $('#countryname, #statename, #cityname').hide();
  if (selectedregion == 'state')
     {
      $('#statename').show();
      }
    else if (selectedregion == 'country')
     {
      $('#countryname').show();
      } 
    else if (selectedregion == 'city')
     {
      $('#cityname').show();
      } 
});
```

Edit--------------------------

For pure js, change the .hide and .show to:

document.getElementById('statename').style.display = 'none';

document.getElementById('statename').style.display = 'block';

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone tell me what mistake am i making?

Your mistake:

```
$("#select1").text()
```

is that you getting text of selected item not correctly.

How to grab the text of select list option correctly:

```
var selectedValue = $("#myselect option:selected").text();
```

As, I see, you know how to use `if` statements in jQuery, but look this:

```
if(selectedValue == 'someValue') {
    // do smth then
}
```

How to achieve what you want? Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#select1").change(function() {
        if($("#select1 option:selected").text()=="select your province")
        {
            $("#select2").hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#select2").show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: now my if statement is working but else statement is not working @sharikov i want my second option list to be visible when the text on my first option list is country

Comment: I edited my answer. Your mistake was you was setting `change` handler on if clause. You just need to show 2nd select there. Also, I suggest to use values, but not text (only if they are digits i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc).

Comment: it seems to be still not working. Else statement is still not been executing

Comment: sure and is there any other way of hiding the option list other than hide function. Because i have just discovered that this function is not cross browser compatible

Comment: You can use 'toggle' function.